# Noob with C# folder select dialog

Tags: c#, io

I'm a newbie to StackOverflow, and to C#. I'm not a software developer! Quick background, I was trained as a research scientist, have worked in biotech for years, and I have written code in lots of languages to get stuff done. C# is my first "real" modern programming language. In short, I am not part of the "in" crowd. Yet.

Learning new stuff doing basic exercises, and as usual, the basic stuff is what has me stuck. I am creating a simple form (winforms), one button click to select a folder. Maybe I'll write the folder name to a text box to be sure it worked.

I don't like the FolderBrowserDialog, so I downloaded WindowsAPICodePack-Core and installed it. Here's my code not working.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Dialogs;

namespace getDirOpenFile
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void chooseFolder_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            {
                var dialog = new CommonOpenFileDialog();
                dialog.IsFolderPicker = true;
                if (dialog.ShowDialog() == CommonFileDialogResult.Ok)
                {
                    // stuff
                }
            }
        }

        private void openFileDialog1_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {

        }        
    }
}
```

Visual studio says:
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'CommonOpenFileDialog' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

NuGet says the package is installed. Side note: "using" statement for "Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Dialogs;" is grayed out as not necessary. What am I missing?

Thanks all,
Aram

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the `CommonOpenFileDialog` does not belong to the assembly you referenced.

You should instead install the [`WindowsAPICodePack-Shell`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAPICodePack-Shell) package, and then add to your file:

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell;
```

And you should be able to run your code.

Comment: Thank you! That did it.